# Efficient algorithm to determine BST

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I would like to know if this correct and efficient way of checking a BST.

My code is to determine, if the tree is a binary search tree. Please feel free to correct, but it has to be the method below and was asked to examine each node in the tree once.

Required to use this method called:`public static boolean isBST(BinaryTree<String> tree)`

Below is my algorithm and code:

```
public static boolean isBST(BinaryTree<String> tree)
{
    return isBST(tree.root);
}

private static boolean isBST(BinaryNode<String> root) {

    if(root==null)
        return true;
    else{
        if(root.getLeftChild().getData().compareTo(root.getData())<0&&root.getRightChild().getData().compareTo(root.getData())>0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I took this approach cause of working with generics and also a static method.

Comment: you need to check if leftChild and rightChild are both BSTs. This is still missing in your code. In other words, you need a recursion

Comment: No. This method is wrong. I recommend that you read this post - http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong, look at `{ left: {value: 5, left: null, right: null} , right: {value 7, left: {value: 10, left: null, right: null} , right: null }`

Comment: @Bhoot thnaks for the link but i saw that they were implementing with max and min integers. But since i'm comparing with strings that method will not be applicable as i am dealing with strings. How do i overcome this

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Seems i have to do recursion but i have links where the max and min integers are used for comparison but since I'm dealing with strings how do i overcome that.

Comment: You actually understand the code instead of blindly copying it. Sorry for being so blunt but the limits are still the same (the lowest level of the tree) - make sure you really understand the integers example and it'll be clear how to generalize it to other types.

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald: I have posted an answer. You can compute the min and max values in your tree beforehand and use them as the bounds.

Comment: @Bhoot Thanks for the help. I really understood it and drew it out on paper to get a clearer picture. But if i wanted to use step 1 as shown below do i have to create a method to determine the min and max value of generic T?

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald If you use the first method, you need to compute the bounds. It is not required in the second method.

Answer (score 2):

The code which you have posted just checks if the immediate children of root node follow the BST property. However, you need to do that for the entire left and right subtree. One way to implement the same is as follows:

```
public static boolean isBST(BinaryTree<String> tree) {
    return isBSTChecker(tree.root, MIN, MAX);
}

public static boolean isBSTChecker(BinaryNode<String> node, T min, T max) {
    if(node == null) return true;
    else if(node.getData().compareTo(min) < 0 || node.getData().compareTo(min) > 0) return false;
    else return isBSTChecker(node.getLeftChild(), min, node.getData()) && isBSTChecker(node.getRightChild(), node.getData(), max);
}
```

In this method, you need to define the MIN and MAX value for your generics. One way to do the same would be to traverse the entire tree and finding minimum and maximum values. The time complexity of this method is O(n) and it uses constant extra space.

Another way in which you can implement your checker is as follows:

```
ArrayList<BinaryNode> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static boolean isBST(BinaryTree<String> tree) {
    inOrder(tree.root);
    return isBSTChecker(list);
}

public static boolean isBSTChecker(ArrayList<BinaryNode> inorder) {
    boolean isBST = true;
    BinaryNode prev = inorder.get(0);
    for(int i=1; i<inorder.size(); i++) {
        BinaryNode curr = inorder.get(i);
        if(curr.getData().compareTo(prev.getData()) < 0) {
             isBST = false;
             break;
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
    return isBST;
}

public static void inOrder(BinaryNode<String> node) {
    if(node == null) return;
    inOrder(node.getLeftChild());
    list.add(node);
    inOrder(node.getRightChild());
}
```

In this method, we first do an inorder traversal over the tree and then check if the result of this traversal is sorted in ascending order. Both the time and space complexity of this method is O(n). You can do away with the linear space complexity by keeping track of the previously visited node during inorder traversal and checking whether the data at current node is greater than previously settled node.

Source: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-program-to-check-if-a-binary-tree-is-bst-or-not/

Comment: thanks very much. This helped. Also i wanted to know how do we define our min and max for generics. Do we just create another method to determine the min and max. Since we know min will be on the left subtree and max be on the right subtree. I also had to make the array list static

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald Sadly, there is no standard generic definition for MIN and MAX values. You either have to compute them from your data (which is linear time operation) or you can determine the data types to which the generics would be casted and use min and max values of those data types.

Comment: Unless the tree is threaded, an inorder traversal does not require constant extra space. If the tree is balanced, traversal requires O(log n) extra space for stack frames. If the tree is not balanced, it could require O(n) extra space.

Comment: @JimMischel I was referring to the arraylist I am using to store the nodes settled during inorder traversal.

Comment: Okay, but then you mention that you can do it without the intermediate list, which is a good thing. In fact, an example of that would be very useful. But eliminating the intermediate list does not make the space complexity constant because the traversal requires a minimum of O(log n) space for stack frames.

Comment: @JimMischel Technically yes. I was talking about the heap space.